# Модальные окна в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Есть Форма1, на которой две кнопки, при нажатии одной открывается одна форма, при нажатии другой, соответственно другая... Как это сделать?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос. А то "Предоставьте" каким-то приказным тоном отдает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если интересует именно модальный режим открытия окна, то в коде обработчика должно быть:

```
// открываем окно
Form2.ShowModal;
// после того как окно закрылось проверяем с каким статусом
if Form2.ModalResult = mrOk then
begin
  // что-то делаем
end;
```

Варианты статуса `ModalResult` можно вешать на одноименное свойство кнопок `TButton` на модальной форме. После того как любая форма открывает модальное окно, до его закрытия она недоступна для пользователя.